# Cannot get the right props value from Vue Component

Tags: javascript, authentication, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to get the value of a props inside of a component, but the returned value is incorrect.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
    <v-app>
    <router-view :authentication="auth"></router-view>
</template>

<script>
    import auth from '../auth.js';
    export default {
      data       : () => ({
          auth           : auth
      }),
      mounted: function () {
          this.$nextTick(function () {
              auth.check()
          })
      }
    }
</script>
```

**Dashboard.vue (gets rendered as the router-view)**

```
<template>
    <h1>You're Logged In!</h1>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['authentication'],
        mounted: function() {
            this.$nextTick(function () {
                console.log(this.authentication.user.authenticated) // Returns false (should be true)
                }
            )
        }
    }
</script>
```

**auth.js**

```
export default {
    user: {
        authenticated: false,
        profile: null
    },
    check() {
        let token = localStorage.getItem('id_token')
        if (token !== null) {
            Vue.http.get(
                'api/user?token=' + token,
            ).then(response => {
                this.user.authenticated = true
                this.user.profile = response.data.user
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The result of `console.log(this.authentication.user.authenticated)` in Dashboard.vue is returned as `false`, but the Vue devtools indicated that the value should be `true` (which is what should be returned).

Here is a screenshot of the props in my `Dasboard.vue` component through the Vue devtools:
[image]

### What I've Tried

1) I've tried changing the value of the `user` object in `auth.js` from `false` to `true` and THEN I get the correct output in `Dashboard.vue`. However, this is no good since the `check()` function is what should be updating the value of the `user` object in `auth.js`.

2) I've logged the result of `this.authentication` in `Dashboard.vue` and I can clearly see that the nested object `user.authenticated` is true, yet the result of `console.log(this.authentication.user.authenticated)` is still false for some reason.

Here is a screenshot of the logged result of `console.log(this.authentication)`:
[image]

Comment: The `mounted` lifecycle handler of `Dashboard.vue` is firing *before* `authenticated` is set to true. `nextTick` isn't going to fix that, the Vue lifecycle is on the order of 15ms and the ajax call is likely taking much longer than that.

Comment: That makes sense @Bert. Any ideas how to resolve the issue?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want to be able for my `mounted` lifecycle handler to read the most up-to-date version of the `authentication` prop in `Dashboard.vue`

Comment: Why do you want to do that in mounted?

Comment: I want to do that in `mounted` in order to redirect a user to another page if the result of `authentication.user.authenticated` is false since I only want authenticated users seeing the `Dashboard` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a different approach. Check for authorization before you even get into Vue, then depending on whether or not the user is authorized, set the appropriate router path.

This would require returning a promise from the `check` method in `auth`.

```
check(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // do your authentication and set user.authenticated appropriately
    resolve(this.user)
  })
}
```

Then your main script looks like this:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App";
import router from "./router";
import auth from "./auth";

auth.check().then(user => {
  if (!user.authenticated) {
    router.push("/NotAuthorized");
  }

  new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    router,
    template: "<App/>",
    components: { App }
  });
});
```

Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/xzvjyx83wp).